# How can I check if an element is in a set with a higher order function

Tags: python, higher-order-functions, membership

I've been struggling with an exercice for several hours, so I'm looking for help.

I got to rewrite this function :

```
def is_in(eq,e,E):
    """ (alpha*alpha -> bool) * alpha * list[alpha] -> bool
    Return True if e is equal to one element of E according to eq"""
    if len(E)==0:
        return False
    elif eq(e,E[0]):
        return True
    else:
        return is_in(eq,e,E[1:])
```

`is_in` verifies if an element is in a set (represented by a list). The thing is, two elements can be the "same", but the operator `==` will return false (for exemple, we consider that [0,1] and [1,0] are the same)

Also, to make `is_in`, I got to use a function I made earlier :

```
def exists(L, p):
    """ list[alpha] * (alpha -> bool) -> bool
    Return True if at least one element x of L is such as p(x)==True"""

    for a in L:
        if p(a):
            return True
    return False
```

We just started studying higher order functions, so I've managed to write several ones but not this one.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can just do `return exists(E, lambda x: eq(x, e))`

Comment: Hello! Is this for learning purpose? To check if an element is in a list in python, you can simply do `if el in mylist`.

Comment: Hey Valentino, yes it's for learning purpose
Thanks Juan for your answer but I'm not sure I can use this

Comment: Yes, `==` would return `False` for `[1,0]` and `[0,1]`, which is why `is_in` takes some *other* predicate besides `==` as an argument.

Comment: Hint: Define a *new* function inside `is_in` which you'll pass as the second argument to `exists`.

Comment: @chepner ok thanks chepner ! I'll try it right now

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose with an actual test function that fails. Where by fails, I mean doesn't do what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tried to do what @chepner told me

```
def is_in(eq, e, E):
    """ (alpha * alpha -> bool) * alpha * list[alpha] -> bool
    Retourne True si e est égal selon eq à un élément de E"""

    if len(E)==0:
        return False
    else:
        def _eq(x):
            for i in E:
                if eq(x, i):
                    return True
            return False
        return exists(E, _eq(e))
```

Does it seem correct to you ?

EDIT :
Ok, I think I have the solution for this one :

```
def is_in(eq, e, E):
    """ (alpha * alpha -> bool) * alpha * list[alpha] -> bool
    Retourne True si e est égal selon eq à un élément de E"""

    def _eq(x):
        return eq(x, e)
    return exists(E, _eq)
```

Comment: You don't need all that. It's a one-liner: just directly `return (e in E)`. No need for recursion. No need to test the length-0 corner-case, `return (e in E)` will handle that case too.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any of that. It's a one-liner: just directly `return (e in E)` :

```
def is_in(e, E):
    return (e in E)

zoo = ['ant','bat','cat','dog','eel']

>>> is_in('fox', zoo)
False
>>> is_in('cat', zoo)
True
>>> is_in('caterpillar', zoo)
False
```

No need for recursion. No need to test the length-0 corner-case, testing `e in E` will handle that too and trivially return False.

(Btw, you can also use `in` with sets as well as lists. Python has a `set()` type.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I know all that, but as I said it's an exercice about higher order function

Comment: What does "higher-order function" mean, "recursive"? or else what?

Comment: Higher order function, by definition, means a function that takes a function as an input or returns a function as an output.

Comment: @MantasKandratavicius: sure, but the higher-order function could still use the `in` operator: `e in E[0]`